# how to concatenate two columns in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x

I want to concatenate two columns is `excel` and make it as a single column.

For example : `column A=12 column B=778`

The output should be `column c=12778`

please find the sample file in the attachment.

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? Just use concat or + and convert the cells to text.

Comment: please help me in achieving  this condition with python.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use the [xlwings](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/index.html) package for this.

```
import xlwings as xw

sht = xw.apps[0].books[0].sheets[0]
sht.range('C1').value = int(str(sht.range('A1').options(numbers=int).value) + str(sht.range('B1').options(numbers=int).value))
```

This snippet will connect to the first active excel application's first worksheet on your system, then grabs the numeric values from cells `A1` and `B1`, convert them to integers then to strings and concatenate them, and finally reconvert it to an integer and pass the final value to cell `C1`.

For further reference please visit the package documentation.

Hope it helps.

Comment: can you please write a code without using xlwings package.

Comment: @kasi_VN in vanilla Python?

Comment: can u help me by using xlrd package.

Comment: i am a beginner in python, please tell me how to open and read excel and execute this operation with code.